# Good method to write data to clipboard

Tags: c#, excel, clipboard

I have a virtual datagridivew that I am custom painting the cells for.

There is no actual data in the datagridview, when it fires the CellPainting event, I pass the x and y coordinates to a custom data structure to retreive the string value to paint in the cell.

This removes the default ctrl+c functionality from the datagridview so....

I would like to know what an effective method for writing this data to the clipboard would be?

The destination of the data will most likely be Excel, so I was thinking of iterating through the selected cells and using a stringbuilder to concantenate them seperated by tabs.

I was also thinking about putting the data into XML maybe?

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom DataSource to transfer your data "the normal" way to the Grid.

So this view is provindg that Data as requested as you currently do in your Paint event, with the possibility for the Control to optimize loading at all times.

Than the ctrl+c would also work and ofcourse all the other cool stuff too :-)

You may want to take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951295.aspx